# Javascript prevent default onclick in code

Tags: javascript

I know that i can do

`<element onclick(function(event))></element>`

but how can i pass event to fuction using just code

```
document.getElementById('elementId').onclick = function(){event.preventDefault()}
```

Comment: It would be better to use [EventTarget.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Why_use_addEventListener). Otherwise, @victor has given you the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put it as a parameter in your on click handler

```
document.getElementById('elementId').onclick = function(event){    
event.preventDefault()    
}
```

Comment: @AidOnline01 if this solves your problem, could you please mark it as an answer?

Comment: of course, it's just prohibited mark it as answer instantly, and i forgotten)